# Compatibility issues with IE8 vs Chrome, Safari, and IE9

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

This could be a challenging one!

I'm very proficient in AJAX and JavaScript even writing OOP JS apps. So you can imagine my frustration when I build a page that works flawlessly in IE7, 8, Opera, FF4. I mean, unless the world has changed, IE and FF were all you ever needed, really, for compatibility testing.... right??

WRONG (apparently)

I have a complicated js app that works great, as I said. But if fails in Chrome and Safari. The scripting is loaded with dynamic DOM creation and attribute manipulation and I think I've isolated the issue within one set of scripting... below.

Can any of you geniouses recognize any JS here that may have issues with Chrome and Safari? I think I've nailed it down to .style calls (think CSS) that break the presentation. BTW, it ends up being the SAME EXACT problem when I test with IE9... this may be a clue.

I've searched far and wide on the web and either I'm missing the correct key words to search for or... whatever :)

```
    for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    SupportContent.hrefArray[SupportContent.hrefArray.length] = list[i];
    if(i == list.length-1)SupportContent.bookMarkListing();
    ChangeDOM.addChildren({'elType':'div','id':'title~'+list[i]},this.displaySupport);
        var thisTitle = document.getElementById('title~'+list[i]);
        thisTitle.style.paddingTop = '15px';
        thisTitle.onclick = function(){SupportContent.manageLineOpenClose('arrow~'+this.id.split('~',2)[1]+'~c')};
        ChangeDOM.addChildren({'elType':'span','id':'arrowCont~'+list[i]},thisTitle);
            var thisArrow = document.getElementById('arrowCont~'+list[i]);
            thisArrow.style.float = 'left';
            thisArrow.style.width = '30px';
            ChangeDOM.addChildren({'elType':'img','id':'arrow~'+list[i]+'~c','src':'/images/support/arrowClose.jpg','border':'0'},thisArrow);
    ChangeDOM.addChildren({'elType':'div', 'id':'tabs~'+list[i]},this.displaySupport);//tabs container
        var tabContainer = document.getElementById('tabs~'+list[i]);
        tabContainer.style.borderBottom = '5px #35383c solid';
        tabContainer.style.paddingTop = '5px';
        tabContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#151515';
        tabContainer.style.marginTop = '10px';
    ChangeDOM.addChildren({'elType':'div', 'id':'content~'+list[i]},this.displaySupport);//contentContainer
        var contentContainer = document.getElementById('content~'+list[i]);
        contentContainer.style.display = 'none';
        contentContainer.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    for(var j=1;j<5;j++){
        this.buildTab(j,tabNames[j],list[i]);
        this.setContent(j,list[i],contentContainer);
    };
```

BTW... the ChangeDOM class is a custom class I've created to manipulate the DOM. This code is below...

```
//custom utility to change the DOM
    //adds children to given node 
    //"keys" format  - {"['elType'] or [element attribute] or     ['text']":"[element type] or [attribute property] or [actual text],"":""...}
function ChangeDOM(){}
ChangeDOM.prototype.addChildren = function(keys,parentNodeObject){
//alert(parentNodeObject.id);
var elName = '';
if (keys["elType"] == 'input'){ 
    if (keys["type"] == 'radio'){
        try{
            elName = document.createElement('<input type="radio" name="fldID" />');  
        }catch(err){  
            elName = document.createElement('input'); 
        }
        try{elName.setAttribute('type','radio');}catch(err){elName.type = 'radio'};
        elName.setAttribute('name','fldID'); 
    }
}
if(elName == '')elName=document.createElement(keys["elType"]);
for(var key in keys){
    if(key != "elType"){
        switch(key){
            case('type'):   if (keys[key] == 'radio')break;
                            elName.type = keys[key];
                            break;
            case('name'):   elName.name = keys[key];
                            break;
            case('value'):  elName.value = keys[key];
                            break;
            case('id'):     elName.id = keys[key];
                            break;
            case('href'):   elName.href = keys[key];
                            break;
            default:        if(key !='text')elName.setAttribute(key,keys[key]);
                            break;
        }
    }
}
parentNodeObject.appendChild(elName);
if(keys['text']){
    if(keys["elType"] == "input"){
        this.addChildren({'text':keys['text']},parentNodeObject);
    }else{
        var txt=document.createTextNode(keys[key]);
        elName.appendChild(txt);
    }
}
return;
}
    //clears all children from given node
ChangeDOM.prototype.clearChildren = function(parentNodeObject){
        if(parentNodeObject.childNodes){
            var nodechildren = new Array();
            nodechildren = parentNodeObject.childNodes;
            if(nodechildren.length>0)for(i=0;nodechildren.length;i++)parentNodeObject.removeChild(parentNodeObject.lastChild);
        }
        return;
    }
    //updates text for a given node
ChangeDOM.prototype.updateText = function(newText,parentNodeObject){
        this.clearChildren(parentNodeObject);
        this.addChildren({'text':newText},parentNodeObject);
    }
```

Comment: this is why people use frameworks.  let someone else worry about how to make things work across multiple browsers.

Comment: Have you considered using the WebKit web inspector/debugger to see what goes on?

Comment: Chrome has a console window which shows errors (file name and line). Try using that to find the error(s).

Comment: "...unless the world has changed, IE and FF were all you ever needed, really, for compatibility testing..." - the world hasn't changed: things have *never* worked that way. Unless of course by "compatibility testing" you mean "compatibility with IE and FF"...

Comment: My mony is on the `~` in your id's unless you actually use those as some kind of identifier for text replacement elsewhere in your js.

Comment: And who ever told you you didnt need to test for Webkit (ie, Chrome, Safari, and others)???

Comment: ok, so my web testing is sooooo last year! Can someone give me more information of where to go for webkit testing? I will try removing the tilde character... good suggestion! Hadn't thought of that one

Comment: zneak - you mentioned a WebKit web inpsector/debugger. I'll google it, but does it work with dynamic js?

Comment: Safari has Web Inspector built in, it's pretty similar to FireBug, but you have to turn it on. Go to Preferences, Advanced tab, and click on 'Show Develop menu in menu bar'

Comment: Like David said... you should be using a framework like jQuery to avoid problems like this. Having said that, pop a demo in JSFiddle.net so we can debug it if you're really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was not the tilde or bad .js. It was what I thought... css. Once I started specifying the widths of the boxes my scripting was building it all came together. Other browsers, it seems, was assuming widths.

Thanks everyone for your input.

On another note, though I do like JQuery and am using it from time to time, I like the raw power of JS better. And even with using JQuery, I would have had to still specify widths to get it right.